# Mysql - "EXPLAIN SELECT" from a VIEW is looking in all rows of the main table

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have 2 tables:

- `t_cities` (`idCity`, `idCountry`, `name`, `population`)
- `t_countries` (`idCountry`, `name`)

`t_cities` has 50000 rows so I create a VIEW with the cities from UK (only 1100):

```
CREATE VIEW v_city_uk AS SELECT * FROM t_cities WHERE idCountry = 140
```

Everything is fine so far, I get a VIEW with 1100 rows.
The query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_city_uk
```

returns 1100, but the EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_city_uk
```

says that it is checking the 50000 rows to execute this query. Why?
Is there any way to make this not happen? Because I create the view to speed up the queries not to be the same.

---

**EDIT**: An "aggregate table" is what I need, Thanks to matthewdavidson.

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table? My first guess would be that the view still needs to execute the select and where clause, so it still needs to determine the subset you are looking for.

Comment: Add an index on `(idCountry)`.

Answer (score 2):

Because a view is not a *precompiled* query or a *stored result*, it is a *predefined* query.  It executes the SELECT statements in the view, *every time*. Otherwise, a view would never get updated.  A view is a representation of a query.  It's a convenient shorthand for the programmer, but not for the machine.

In other words, when you

```
SELECT something FROM YourView
```

And YourView is defined by

```
CREATE VIEW YourView AS SELECT stuff FROM sometable 
INNER JOIN othertable ON sometable.column = othertable.column
```

what's actually being run is

```
 SELECT something FROM 
(SELECT stuff FROM sometable 
INNER JOIN othertable ON sometable.column = othertable.column)
```

If you want to store a result, you should use an aggregate table.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html): -The view definition is “frozen” at creation time, so changes to the underlying tables afterward do not affect the view definition. For example, if a view is defined as SELECT * on a table, new columns added to the table later do not become part of the view. So i thought it was like a "permanent" _temporary_table

Comment: BUT "aggregate table" That is the answer, f* that view, thank you very much Matthew

Comment: It's not about whether the definition changes, it's about whether the result set changes.  A view recreates itself every time it is queried, using the query that it is made with.